# Optimal way to use if-statement in MVC View

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing a summer internship as a web developer and this friday I had a problem I wasn't sure exactly which way was the "best" way to solve. I don't have the code here, but as it's not a code/syntax problem, but more of a "how do I go about this"-problem.

Basically, I have a model with a Customer class which I, in my controller, assign values from the database. So in my CustomerController I have a LINQ query which grabs values from the database and assigns these values to the corresponding variables in the Customer Model. Then, in my CustomerView, I show these variables in a table for each Customer. So I have a loop that basically says:

```
foreach (item in Model) 
<td>@item.Name</td>
<td>@item.Age</td>
<td>selfmadeDecryptFunction(@item.Email)</td>
```

and so on. Thing is, another developer has written a crypt/decrypt function which doesn't work if the value is NULL or 0. Sometimes, the @item.Email is empty which because of this decryption results in an error. Because of this, I want to just print the string NULL when @item.Email is null, and not run the decrypt function.

What is the "best" way to go about this? Do I write inline javascript if-else? Is there something I can do in the LINQ query or in the CustomerController? What's the "correct" way? I don't really want to go ask my coworkers about this because it's quite basic, and I could fix this myself, but I want to know what the correct way to solve this problem is.

Comment: Will your co-workers be peer-reviewing your solution before you commit?

Comment: Are you asking where to put the `if`, in the controller, in the view or in a javascript file? Or are you asking how to write the `if`?

Comment: yeah... that's basically what is boils down to. what's best practice?

Comment: There isn't one. Put it where it belongs. If it's a pure presentational thing, probably put it in the view. Otherwise put it anywhere except the view. Only you know your architecture enough to judge where it belongs better.

Comment: Concepts such as 'Best practice' are usually a subjective matter.    In general, you should choose the simplest working (correct) solution, and discuss these kinds of style issues with your peers during the code review.      If your peers reject your solution, you've got the opportunity to ask them why and what they'd recommend you do instead.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks guys. Yeah, I feel like these first weeks I'm always second guessing my code in ways like this, but yeah -- I'll have to trust that my solutions are good ones, and learn from my co workers when they point out the times they aren't good.

Comment: Solution has no problem for me. But if they specify that the decryptfunction should sit on its own class with interface, then you can factor out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said:

> Because of this, I want to just print the string NULL when @item.Email
>   is null, and not run the decrypt function.

You can simply apply an `if` construct to solve that:

```
    foreach (item in Model)
    { 
      <td>@item.Name</td>
      <td>@item.Age</td>
      @if(item.Email!=null)
      {
       <td>item.Email</td>
      }
      else
      {
        <td>NULL</td>
      }
   }
```

In the code above if `@item.Email` is not null then it will be as it is (real value from Model), and if it is null then NULL will be printed on a place where should be `@item.Email` written.

Comment: thanks! this is actually what i wrote at work, so this is all good, but i'm wondering if it's considered "good" code? for me, it feels kind of iffy to do logic in the view, instead of doing it in the controller, but at the same time it feels like the simplest solution.

Comment: @akre_11 it is good code,  don't worry :) and if this answer helped you please accept it and vote up  :)

Comment: @akre_11 you could do your logic in the Controller also, for example you might check if email that you retrieved from database is null then set it's value to a string "NULL" (myObject.Email = "NULL") and "NULL" would be printed, but this logic is also fine :)

Comment: You can use coalesce in your LINQ query